# How can we see the electrons?

Tags: electrons

[image: Electrons beam shown inside Cathode Ray Tube]

As you can see the blue glows is the electrons flowing inside the cathode ray tube under vacuum condition. My question is how can we see the electrons in the setup? electrons are everywhere but why don't they glow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blue glow is cause by free electrons (i.e. those not bound in atoms) colliding with some residual gas molecules in the tube. Even though it's under vacuum, there is still some gas present (perhaps even designed this way, to create the lighting effect).

In a collision, the gas molecule can absorb some energy from the electron and undergo an electronic excitation, which is short-lived. When the molecule relaxes or de-excites, it emits a photon of light.

The light is blue because this matches the spacing between two energy levels in nitrogen.

Further reading at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionized-air_glow

Comment: I would say that it's not some residual gas, but that the tube was designed/made to contain a low pressure of nitrogen to make the effect more noticeable.